# How to use Managed Identity for a Python application which uses an Azure AI service?

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-ai

I am following [this tutorial](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-services/Instructions/setup.html) which explains how to access an Azure text analytics service from a Python application using service principal. In the end, a password is used. The approach works for `dev`/`test` but for `prod`, the recommended way is to use managed identities.

The service principal has `get`, `list` access to the key vault.

The process gives me some parameters of service principal which I use in the Python code:

```json
{
  "appId": "...",
  "displayName": "api://ai-app-mc",
  "password": "...",
  "tenant": "..."
}
```

How do I go about using managed identities such that I can access an Azure AI service from Python code without having to store any password or key in the code or `.env` file?

The code in the tutorial runs from Visual Studio. If I want to use managed identities, can I still use Visual Studio do I need to deploy the application in a VM and then assign managed identity to the VM and then give the managed identify access to the AzureAI` service?   The tasks I have done so far:

- went to Azure AI service and enabled managed identify. I suppose this decides who can access the service.
- I created a Cognitive services user for the resource group

I suppose I have to assign roles but shall I do it at subscription level, resource group level?

Where does the Python code I want to run come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps.

1. Enable managed identities in your host that is in a VM. Follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm) for more about managed identities in VM.
2. Next, give access to this managed identity to your language service. You need to assign the `Cognitive Services Language Reader` role to your managed identity.

[image]

3. Use the code below.

```py
import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential, DefaultAzureCredential

endpoint = "https://<resource_name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

sys_iden = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="ad7xxxxxxxfec")
text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=sys_iden)

documents = [
    """I had the best day of my life. I decided to go sky-diving and it made me appreciate my whole life so much more.
    I developed a deep-connection with my instructor as well, and I feel as if I've made a life-long friend in her.""",
    """This was a waste of my time. All of the views on this drop are extremely boring, all I saw was grass. 0/10 would
    not recommend to any divers, even first-timers.""",
    """This was pretty good! The sights were ok, and I had fun with my instructors! Can't complain too much about my experience""",
    """I only have one word for my experience: WOW!!! I can't believe I have had such a wonderful skydiving company right
    in my backyard this whole time! I will definitely be a repeat customer, and I want to take my grandmother skydiving too,
    I know she'll love it!"""
]

result = text_analytics_client.analyze_sentiment(documents, show_opinion_mining=True)
docs = [doc for doc in result if not doc.is_error]

print("Let's visualize the sentiment of each of these documents")
for idx, doc in enumerate(docs):
    print(f"Document text: {documents[idx]}")
    print(f"Overall sentiment: {doc.sentiment}")
```

Here, I used `ManagedIdentityCredential`, which by default uses `system-assigned identity`, and by providing the client id, you can use `user-assigned identity`.

Output:

[image]